# Network Manager stopped recognizing wired connections

Tags: linux, networking, opensuse, wired-networking

I'm using OpenSuse 12.3 with a Gnome interface. I am able to connect to any wireless network but my network manager just stopped recognizing wired ones. I'm not even show the "wired connection" menu. Everything was working fine until I disabled graphically the wired connection (by clicking off). Since them I am unable to use any wired connection. Here is the output of ifconfig -a:

```
eth1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr C4:46:19:0E:D4:18  
      inet addr:192.168.1.7  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:211384 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:70075
      TX packets:194964 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:224882156 (214.4 Mb)  TX bytes:28579395 (27.2 Mb)
      Interrupt:17 

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:9406 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:9406 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:760489 (742.6 Kb)  TX bytes:760489 (742.6 Kb)
```

netstat -rn outputs this :

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
```

dmesg | grep eth outputs this :

```
[   15.979769] eth0: Broadcom BCM4353 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 5.100.82.112
[   15.986506] systemd-udevd[343]: renamed network interface eth0 to eth1
[ 1485.183810] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready
```

and iwconfig this :

```
eth1  IEEE 802.11  Access Point: Not-Associated   
      Link Quality:4  Signal level:190  Noise level:165
      Rx invalid nwid:0  invalid crypt:0  invalid misc:0

lo    no wireless extensions.
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `netstat -rn` ?
`iwconfig` ?

Comment: @september I just edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

OK, eth1 - wireless interface. Almost sure that eth0 wired interface.
Try :

> ~# ifup eth0

and check your interfaces with `ifconfig` again.

---

Update:

Hmmm...

> systemd-udevd[343]: renamed network interface eth0 to eth1

I think your MAC address of eth0 was changed. Read more [here](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/renamed-network-interface-eth0-eth1-help-200405271.html). Try to comment eth0 record in  /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules and reboot.

Comment: ifup eth0 outputs "Interface eth0 is not available". By the way I'm on OpenSuse and the network is by default handled by NetworkManager so I had to manually switch to ifup.

Comment: @iamdede please provide output of `ifconfig -a` instead of `ifconfig`

Comment: OK I have edited my post again.

Comment: Try to restart network `# /etc/init.d/network restart` according http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/novell-sles-suse-restart-stop-networking-services-networking/

Comment: It didn't work, and that's what I expected as it doesn't change when I restart the computer neither.

Comment: Provide `dmesg | grep eth`
and try http://sfdoccentral.symantec.com/sf/5.0RU1/linux/html/vcs_install_linux/ch03s03s03.htm

Comment: I have edited my post again,

Comment: From what I've seen on this error, I need to edit the file /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules, but how can I find the MAC address of eth0 since it doesn't seem to be recognized by the system? I read this page : http://blog.hio.fr/2010/01/20/linux-udev-renamed-network-interface-eth0-to-eth1.html (it's in French)

Comment: I have edited my post

Comment: There is no eth0 in this file. This is how it looks : # PCI device 0x14e4:0x4353 (wl)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="c4:46:19:0e:d4:18", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"